# Extract string with numbers using regex for numbers between 0 to 999

Tags: regex

In the below phrase i need to extract `/testcard-directory/100` where the number at the last can vary between 0 to 999.

> [Tue Jun 27 02:40:25.207457 2020] [:error] [pid 4085] [client
> 23.23.23.32:34223] Server IP: 172.17.0.3\nUser agent: Amazon CloudFront\nServer time: 2020-06-27 19:40:25\nRequestURI:
> **/testcard-directory/100**\nMessage: mongodb:27017: Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for 30.000000 seconds\n\nTrace:\n#0

I tried this

```
\/flashcard-directory\/[1-9][0-9]
```

but the last number is not getting picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
/testcard-directory/[0-9]*
```

Demo :

```
$estcard-directory/100\nMessage: mongodb:27017: Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for 30.000000 seconds\n\nTrace:\n#0' | grep -o '/testcard-directory/[0-9]*                                                                                         <
> ' 
/testcard-directory/100
$
```

Comment: This is matching from `/testcard-directory/` (without any digits) to `/testcard-directory/999999999999999999999999999999999...`

Answer (score 0):

**regex:** `\/testcard-directory\/\d{0,3}`

https://regex101.com/r/DDuKsX/1

Answer (score 0):

Use: `^\/testcard-directory\/\d{1,3}$`

Here is a Javascript implementation easily portable:

```js
var test = [
    '/testcard-directory/',
    '/testcard-directory/0',
    '/testcard-directory/123',
    '/testcard-directory/1234',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' : '+/^\/testcard-directory\/\d{1,3}$/.test(a);
}));
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/1GWHdd/1)